# Different definitions of projective objects

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

There are various characterizations for an $R$-module to be projective. Two of them can be generalized to any category:

i) $P$ is an object such that given morphisms $\alpha: A \rightarrow B$ and $\varphi: P \rightarrow B$ such that $\alpha$ is an epimorphism, there exists a morphism $\widetilde{\varphi}: P \rightarrow A$ such that $\alpha \circ \widetilde{\varphi} = \varphi$. (Lifting property) In other words, the functor $\text{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(P,-): \mathsf{C} \rightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ preserves epimorphisms.

ii) $P$ is an object such that every epimorphism with codomain $P$ splits.

It is easy to see that (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) holds in general, by taking $\varphi = \text{id}_P$. Also if the category has the property that for every object $X$ there is an epimorphism $\pi:P \rightarrow X$ where $P$ satisfies (i) (an abelian category with this property is said to have  *enough projectives*), we can show the reverse implication (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i).

My first question: Does (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i) hold in general? I suspect the answer is no. If so, under which conditions does it hold?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For clarity, let us reserve the phrase **projective object** for an object satisfying (i) and use **choice object** for an object satisfying (ii). (One formulation of the axiom of choice is to say that every object in $\textbf{Set}$ is a choice object.)

**Proposition.** If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category such that

- all pullbacks exist, and
- epimorphisms are preserved by pullbacks,

then choice objects in $\mathcal{C}$ are projective objects.

*Proof.* Let $C$ be a choice object in $\mathcal{C}$, let $f : A \twoheadrightarrow B$ be an epimorphism, and let $h : C \to B$ be any morphism. Let $r : A \times_B C \to C$ be the pullback of $f$ along $h$. By hypothesis, $r$ is an epimorphism, so there is a morphism $s : C \to A \times_B C$ with $r \circ s = \textrm{id}$. Let $\ell : A \times_B C \to A$ be the pullback of $h$ along $f$, and set $g = \ell \circ s$. By construction, $$f \circ g = f \circ \ell \circ s = h \circ r \circ s = h$$
so we have the required lifting of $h$ along $f$. Thus $C$ is projective. $\quad \blacksquare$

This is a much milder assumption than assuming $\mathcal{C}$ has enough projectives. For example, every topos and every abelian category satisfies the hypotheses of the proposition. If $\mathcal{C}$ is a regular category then the same proof shows that every choice object is regular-projective. (A regular-projective object is an object with the lifting property for regular epimorphisms.) In some cases every epimorphism is regular: for example, the category of groups is a regular category in which every epimorphism is regular.