# Any epi with codomain $P$ is split implies $P$ is projective

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I'm struggling to prove that if any epi with codomain $P$ splits, then $P$ is a projective object. The converse direction I proved by factoring the identity to give a right inverse of the pi.

How can I prove this claim?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the environment you're assuming?

Comment: This has now popped up in the "Related" section: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135777/different-definitions-of-projective-objects?rq=1 (presumably because the question has been edited to a correct version). I'm inclined to say that this could be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: Consider the category with three objects $P$, $X$ and $Y$, and two non-identity morphisms $f : P \to X$ and $\pi : Y \to X$ (and the only possible composition rules). Then every epimorphism with codomain $P$ splits (there is only one such epimorphism, the identity...). But $P$ is not projective: $\pi$ is an epimorphism, but $f$ does not factor through $\pi$.

---

*Wrong answer below!*

I'm pretty sure that you mean "any epi with **co**domain $P$ splits". Compare with the case of projective modules over a ring: exact sequences $0 \to A \to B \to P \to 0$ split when $P$ is projective. And for example $\mathbb{Z} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't split even though $\mathbb{Z}$ is projective in the category of abelian groups.

Let $f : P \to X$ be a morphism, and $\pi : Y \to X$ an epimorphism. Take the pullback:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y \times_X P @>{f'}>> Y \\
@V{\pi'}VV @V{\pi}VV \\
P @>{f}>> X
\end{CD}$$
Then since <s>epimorphisms are stable under pullbacks</s> (**They are not! this argument is wrong.**), the projection $\pi' : Y \times_X P \to P$ is epimorphic. By hypothesis it splits, so let $s : P \to P \times_X Y$ be a splitting, ie. $\pi' \circ s = \operatorname{id}_P$. Let $g = f' \circ s : P \to Y$. Then $\pi \circ g = \pi \circ f' \circ s = f \circ \pi' \circ s = f$ and so $f$ factors through $\pi$.

---

Note: this assumes that pullbacks exist in the category we are considering (generally they do in homological algebra, but one has to be careful). Otherwise the claim is false. (Edit: And the argument is wrong anyway!)

Comment: Sorry, corrected domain to codomain.

Comment: One needs some hypotheses on the category involved.

Comment: @Exterior: scrap the whole thing. I don't know what I was thinking: epimorphism are *not* stable under pullbacks! They are stable under pushouts... (It's monomorphisms that are stable under pullbacks)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi strangely enough, I think I subconsciously remembered Zhen Lin's answer in that question. It is one of the reasons I didn't say the setting is an abelian category. At any rate, I don't mind these extra hypotheses - having pullbacks which also preserve epis.